# How can i check if iframe content is loaded and visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, external

I use an iframe on a website to show external websites.
Some external websites doesn't allow the representation in a frame.

Does anybody know how I can check the content in the iframe? I will check if there is any content presented.

Comment: _some external websites doesn't allow the representation in a frame_ this is by design. You can add `<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">` to avoid embedding. Why you are embedding external websites?

Comment: short answer is you really can't when site uses frame buster methods

Comment: _“Does anybody know how I can check the content in the iframe?”_ – you can’t, because of the Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code example

```
var $iframe=$("#id").find('iframe');
if ($iframe.data('src')){ // only do it once per iframe
   $iframe.prop('src', $iframe.data('src')).data('src', false);
}
```